# Spark dataframe from Json string with nested key

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have several columns to be extracted from json string. However one field has nested values. Not sure how to deal with that?

Need to explode into multiple rows to get values of field name, Value1, Value2.

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("1", """{"k": "foo", "v": 1.0}""", "some_other_field_1"),
  ("2", """{"p": "bar", "q": 3.0}""", "some_other_field_2"),
  ("3",
    """{"nestedKey":[ {"field name":"name1","Value1":false,"Value2":true},
      |                 {"field name":"name2","Value1":"100","Value2":"200"}
      |]}""".stripMargin, "some_other_field_3")

).toDF("id","json","other")

df.show(truncate = false)
val df1= df.withColumn("id1",col("id"))
  .withColumn("other1",col("other"))
  .withColumn("k",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.k"))
  .withColumn("v",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.v"))
  .withColumn("p",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.p"))
  .withColumn("q",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.q"))
  .withColumn("nestedKey",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.nestedKey"))
    .select("id1","other1","k","v","p","q","nestedKey")
df1.show(truncate = false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the nestedKey using `from_json` and explode it:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "nestedKey", 
    expr("explode_outer(from_json(nestedKey, 'array<struct<`field name`:string, Value1:string, Value2:string>>'))")
).select("*", "nestedKey.*").drop("nestedKey")

df2.show
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+----------+------+------+
|id1|            other1|   k|   v|   p|   q|field name|Value1|Value2|
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+----------+------+------+
|  1|some_other_field_1| foo| 1.0|null|null|      null|  null|  null|
|  2|some_other_field_2|null|null| bar| 3.0|      null|  null|  null|
|  3|some_other_field_3|null|null|null|null|     name1| false|  true|
|  3|some_other_field_3|null|null|null|null|     name2|   100|   200|
+---+------------------+----+----+----+----+----------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Is it possible to alias those nested keys like `field name` as 'My Field' etc

Comment: yes, you can rename columns using `.withColumnRenamed`

Answer (score 0):

i did it in one dataframe

````
 val df1= df.withColumn("id1",col("id"))
    .withColumn("other1",col("other"))
    .withColumn("k",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.k"))
    .withColumn("v",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.v"))
    .withColumn("p",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.p"))
    .withColumn("q",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.q"))
    .withColumn("nestedKey",get_json_object(col("json"),"$.nestedKey"))
  .withColumn(
    "nestedKey",
    expr("explode_outer(from_json(nestedKey, 'array<struct<`field name`:string, Value1:string, Value2:string>>'))")
  ).withColumn("fieldname",col("nestedKey.field name"))
    .withColumn("valueone",col("nestedKey.Value1"))
    .withColumn("valuetwo",col("nestedKey.Value2"))
   .select("id1","other1","k","v","p","q","fieldname","valueone","valuetwo")```


still working to make it more elegant
````